# In Swift, my Alert View controller has two buttons, one cancel and one add. How do i program the add button to actually add to the list

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have created a bar button item. The bar button item is specifically the '+' or add button. I have created a UIAlertViewController that has two buttons come up when the '+' button is pressed. One is 'Add' and one is 'Cancel'. The cancel button works fine because it automatically cancels the Alert, but I want to program the + button to actually let me add to the cell view. Can someone please tell me the code that will go into the add button function.

Comment: When you add the button, you also add the block handler for the button.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with a `UIAlertViewController` class...  `UIAlertView` was deprecated in iOS 8.  If this question is about using a `UIAlertController`, then here is an example.

Assume a backing array called `data`: `var data = [1,2,3,4,5]` that provides data to a table view.

When a user taps on the `UIBarButtonItem`, the following method is called:

```
@IBAction func addItem(sender: AnyObject) {
    let avc = UIAlertController(title: "Add item", message: "Are you sure?", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let addItem = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .Default) { action in
        let lastNumber = self.data.last
        if var ln = lastNumber {
            self.data.append(++ln)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    avc.addAction(addItem)

    let cancelItem = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    avc.addAction(cancelItem)

    presentViewController(avc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

You first create an instance of `UIAlertController` with the `.Alert` style.  You next add `UIAlertAction`s for adding an item and canceling the alert.

`UIAlertAction`s have a parameter called `handler` that takes a closure.  This closure is how you associate actions with the buttons.

For example, the `addItem` alert action uses the trailing closure syntax.  The closure adds some data to the table view's model, and then calls `reloadData()` to show the data.